# mysql order by a specific variable on the first row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php to query my mysql database. I'm having trouble ordering the data on my table to my liking. I would like the first row to be the username I defined in the variable $username and then the rest ordered by username as seen in the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM report ORDER BY username = '$username', username DESC
```

Comment: Can it be in more details on table structure and data you have inserted?

Comment: it was unclear can you explain more specific?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear maybe the updated query will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `UNION` query then. Let the first SELECT only return the matching $username, and the second SELECT everything except that - and ordered.

```
(SELECT *, 1 AS prio FROM tbl WHERE username = ?)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *, 2 AS prio FROM tbl WHERE username <> ?)
ORDER BY prio ASC, username DESC
```

This adds a fake column `prio` to ORDER the desired username row first, and only then by username DESC.

(This could actually be shorter with an expression instead of `1` and `2` values, but I guess the UNION workaround makes a simpler example.)

Comment: The `?` is a placeholder. If you're using the dated mysql_* functions, then you'll of course have to use your cumbersome escaping + variable interpolation etc there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Mario's answer:

If you use **Limit** then also it will work fine without using fake column(s) (1,2/prio)

```
(SELECT * FROM report WHERE username = '$username') union (SELECT * FROM report order by username DESC limit 100)
```

Thanks,